# Pandas cumsum multiple columns in groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I am attempting to get the .cumsum of oil_prod + water_prod + gas_prod by patternname & patternset based on my .loc slice.

What I have below is currently returning all 3 columns cumsum per book_date per groupby, however, the intended output is to have only 1 cumsum column, per book_date per groupby.

I haven't figured out how to sum them together for one result.

`df.loc[df['book_date'] >= df['wf_start_date'], ['patternname','patternset','oil_prod_rb','water_prod_rb','gas_prod_rb']]
.groupby(by = ['patternset', 'patternname']).cumsum().round()`

Comment: add a `.sum(axis=1)` to sum the cumsums

Comment: @ALollz Answer was what I needed.

Comment: @ALollz why not submit your comment as an answer?